# Imagemagic: Resizing image increase image size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, imagemagick, paperclip, carrierwave

I have an image

And I need to create thumbnail

I do it with next command

```
convert "source.png" -auto-orient -resize "350x350>" "destination.png"
```

But resized image has larger size then original

[Original image](https://yadi.sk/i/W-ZbMBQ1sXH5yQ): 262x377 PNG(24-bit color) 9.16KB

[Resized  image](https://yadi.sk/i/g46yUDveX8pW9Q): 243x350 PNG(24-bit color) 44.56KB

I tried to resize with compression options

```
convert "source.png" -auto-orient -resize "350x350>" -colors 256 -quality 50 -depth 8 "destination.png"
```

But result image also larger than original

[Original image](https://yadi.sk/i/W-ZbMBQ1sXH5yQ): 262x377 PNG(24-bit color) 9.16KB

[Resized  image](https://yadi.sk/i/9yzBMwD3lpduQw): 243x350 PNG(8-bit color) 32.80KB

Why is this happening? And how to make image with a smaller size?

Comment: Resizing introduces new colors that increase the file size. Also PNG is compressed and the compression between the input and output may be different. If you want and 8-bit result, then add PNG8 to your output as PNG8:destination.png

Comment: Is it possible resize image with the same colors, compression etc as original and receive proportional file size?

Comment: To ensure the same colors, you would need to use -sample rather than -resize. -resize interpolates between pixels, so it creates new colors. -sample just takes a whole pixels every so often when minifying. Alternately, you can use -filter point -resize to use whole pixels. If you do not have too many colors, you can make an image of the unique colors and use -remap to force the output to use the same colors as the input by coloring them to the closest color from the color table. image.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  +repage just before the destination image

> -repage geometry
>   Adjust the canvas and offset information of the image.
>   This option is like -page but acts as an image operator rather than a setting. You can separately set the canvas size or the offset of the image on that canvas by only providing those components. 
>   See Image Geometry for complete details about the geometry argument.
>   If a ! flag is given the offset given is added to the existing offset to move the image relative to its previous position. This useful for animation sequences. 
>   A given a canvas size of zero such as '0x0' forces it to recalculate the canvas size so the image (at its current offset) will appear completely on that canvas (unless it has a negative offset).
>   Use +repage to completely remove/reset the virtual canvas meta-data from the images. 
>   The -set 'page' option can be used to directly assign virtual canvas meta-data.

Comment: Could you show working example please? I tried to add repage option
convert "source.png" -auto-orient -resize "350x350>" +repage "destination.png"
but it didn't change result file size(

Comment: I thought what you did would have fixed it